# Determinant of 5x5 Matrix with 6 Adjacent Zeros

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, determinant

### Problem

Prove $ \ \
\begin{vmatrix}
    a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3} & a_{4} & a_{5} \\
    b_{1} & b_{2} & b_{3} & b_{4} & b_{5} \\
    c_{1} & c_{2} & c_{3} & c_{4} & c_{5} \\
    d_{1} & d_{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    e_{1} & e_{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix} 
= 0.
$

*Restrictions:* All variables are nonzero.

### Attempt

My first attempt was to reduce the bottom two rows to zero, and another attempt was to transform the matrix into a lower triangular matrix. Neither worked.

### Notes

If anyone can provide me detailed steps on how to achieve the RHS, I'd be very appreciative! Thanks!

Comment: Any restrictions on the $d$ and $e$ entries?

Comment: @SeanRoberson Yep, they're nonzero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** By Row Operations you can reduce the bottom two rows

$$\begin{vmatrix}
    a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3} & a_{4} & a_{5} \\
    b_{1} & b_{2} & b_{3} & b_{4} & b_{5} \\
    c_{1} & c_{2} & c_{3} & c_{4} & c_{5} \\
    d_{1} & d_{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    e_{1} & e_{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
    a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3} & a_{4} & a_{5} \\
    b_{1} & b_{2} & b_{3} & b_{4} & b_{5} \\
    c_{1} & c_{2} & c_{3} & c_{4} & c_{5} \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & d_1e_{2}-d_2e_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix} $$
Then, by expnasion you get
$$\begin{vmatrix}
    a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3} & a_{4} & a_{5} \\
    b_{1} & b_{2} & b_{3} & b_{4} & b_{5} \\
    c_{1} & c_{2} & c_{3} & c_{4} & c_{5} \\
    d_{1} & d_{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    e_{1} & e_{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix} = \left(d_1e_{2}-d_2e_2\right)\begin{vmatrix}
  a_{3} & a_{4} & a_{5} \\
   b_{3} & b_{4} & b_{5} \\
   c_{3} & c_{4} & c_{5} \\
\end{vmatrix} $$

which can be calculated explicitely and  is not identically 0.